# How to align two side by side equations at the top?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, align, alignat

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll}
\text{minimize}  & \|Ax-b\|_\infty &\\
\end{array}
\quad 
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll}
\text{minimize}  & t &\\
\text{subject to} & Ax-b \preceq t \mathbf{1} & \\
& -(Ax-b) \preceq t \mathbf{1}& \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

Generates

[image]

But it would be better if the two minimize lines would align...

Can anyone help me to align the two equations side by side at "minimize"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain it with `[t]` option to `array` environment.

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}[t]{ll@{}ll}
\text{minimize}  & \|Ax-b\|_\infty &\\
\end{array}
\quad 
\begin{array}[t]{ll@{}ll}
\text{minimize}  & t &\\
\text{subject to} & Ax-b \preceq t \mathbf{1} & \\
& -(Ax-b) \preceq t \mathbf{1}& \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]